# ¿Cómo acceder a los métodos de un objeto dentro de una lista en Python?

Tags: python, poo

Tengo la siguiente clase main:

```
#---Importe de clases---
import msvcrt
import os
import prueba.objeto as registro

#---Lista para objetos---
lstObjeto = []

class Main():
    def registroObjeto(self):
        os.system("cls")
        print("----------------------------------------------")
        print("    --- REGISTRO DE OBJETOS ---")
        cod = int(input("Código: "))
        nom = input("Nombre: ")
        print("TIPOS:\n[1]\n[2]\n[3]")
        tip = int(input("Escriba el tipo: "))
        lstObjeto.append(registro.Objeto(cod, nom, tip))
        print("--- El registro del nuevo objeto se ha realizado correctamente. ---")
        print("Presione 'Enter' para regresar...")
        
        print(f"\n {lstObjeto}")
        msvcrt.getch()
```

Y una clase modelo para objetos:

```
class Objeto:
    def __init__(self, cod, nom, tip):
        self.cod = cod
        self.nom = nom
        self.tip = tip

    def getCod(self):
        return self.cod
    
    def setCod(self, cod):
        self.cod = cod

    def getNom(self):
        return self.nom
    
    def setNom(self, nom):
        self.nom = nom

    def getTip(self):
        return self.tip
    
    def setTip(self, tip):
        self.tip = tip
```

Dentro de `lstObjeto` voy agregando todos los objetos que voy creando cada vez que accedo al método `registroObjeto`. Al momento de imprimir la lista de objetos, me retorna el tipo de dato que se está almacenando en la lista junto a su posición en memoria.

Obtengo la siguiente información:

```
 [<clases.objeto.Objeto object at 0x000001C50F4457C0>]
```

¿Cómo puedo entonces acceder a los getters del objeto desde la lista? Así después puedo hacer comparaciones de datos o validaciones.

Comment: redefine su dunder method `__repr__`

Comment: podrías poner la clase Empleado?

Comment: Error mío, no era una clase Empleado, era la clase Objeto.

Comment: pues de igual forma tendrías que modificar la información que te muestra pues aparece la clase Empleado

Comment: Listo, he corregido la información.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El *dunder method* o *método mágico* `__repr__` sirve para definir como se mostrará el objeto al momento de ser impreso, por lo que la solución es redefinir este método para indicar que al momento de ser impreso muestre lo que queramos.

```py
class Objeto:
    ...
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.cod},{self.nom}, {self.tip}"
```